# C++ double data type

Tags: c++, types, double

The data type double is another floating-point type.Then why is it treated as a distinct data type?

Comment: As to opposed to what? I guess you mean why is it distinct from float?

Comment: What confuses you? Why should it not be a distinct data type?

Comment: Why C++ is treated as a distinct language? voting to close as unclear...

Comment: I got this question during one the interview i attended, The interviewer himself didn't gave any answer. @Space_C0wb0y please tell me what makes it distinct from float.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question correctly, but I'm going to assume you mean the difference between a float and a double.

If you refer to http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/ you'll see a list of fundamental data types.

Essentially, a double is a floating point number with higher precision since it uses double the amount of bytes to represent itself. Usually 4 bytes for a float and 8 bytes for a double, but this is totally platform-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

All floating point arithmetic in c++ are done in double unless you explicitly make it float.
for example,

```
float f = 5.0;
f = 2.0*f;
```

In the above, 2.0 is a double, so f will be upgraded to a double, multiplication is performed, down casted to a float and assigned back to f.
Hence unless you are going to run out of memory, its always better to use double than float.